# SQL create table using csv sourcepath

Tags: mysql, sql

I have uploaded the csv file I want to know the code to create a table using that csv file as my source path

Comment: Which database and which programming language?

Comment: Sql database and MySQL programming language

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91966/create-a-table-from-a-csv-file-with-headers